# Get pymongo error: pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have a problem: I wrote python code to communicate with other people through a database that runs on Pymongo. My program was able to connect to the database but could not send files (this is how I tried to get my variable to the database: `db.insert_one (msg)`). The computer gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1394, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luis\PycharmProjects\PresentationGuru2021\main.py", line 133, in <module>
    Startup()
  File "C:\Users\Luis\PycharmProjects\PresentationGuru2021\main.py", line 63, in Startup
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Luis\PycharmProjects\PresentationGuru2021\main.py", line 128, in main
    db.insert_one(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 705, in insert_one
    self._insert(document,
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 620, in _insert
    return self._insert_one(
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 609, in _insert_one
    self.__database.client._retryable_write(
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1552, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1438, in _retry_with_session
    return self._retry_internal(retryable, func, session, bulk)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1462, in _retry_internal
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1308, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1331, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1397, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1297, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 820, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 837, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 672, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 590, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 333, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 710, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 158, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 167, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Can someone help me fix this?
Here is the code (without my password from Pymongo):

```
cluster = MongoClient (
             "mongodb + srv: // Luis: <NOPASSWORT HERE> @ cluster0.mme3c.mongodb.net / myFirstDatabase? retryWrites = true & w = majority")
         db = cluster ["socialMedia"] ["messaging"]
         date = datetime.now (). strftime ("% x")
         person = username
         message = input ("Message:")
         time = datetime.now (). strftime ("% X")
         msg = {"User": person, "message": message, "Date": date, "Time": time}
         print (msg)
         db.insert_one (msg)
```